# Symfony2 + Doctrine2 is not caching results of joined entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, apc

I am using Symfony 2.0.10 with Doctrine 2.1 and have rather simple query (see below), where I want to cache results with APC (version 3.1.7, enabled 1GB of memory for it) via `useResultCache(true, 600)` and keep hydration mode as `\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT`.

The problem is that Many-to-Many relations (`Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection`) don't get cached and every time when main query results are cached the joined entities are set to `null`. The same query is cached well in APC when I set hydration mode to `\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY`, but it is not acceptable solution for me, because I can't redo many templates for this to work.

Please suggest how can I cache all joined entities' properties in APC? Please don't point to documentation, because I think I have learned it by heart trying to solve this issue :)

#### CODE:

```
$property = $em
->createQueryBuilder()
->select('p,u')
->from('MyBundle:Property', 'p')
->leftJoin('p.users', 'u')
->where('p.id in (:id)')
->setParameter('id', 123)
->getQuery()
->useResultCache(true, 60)
->setHydrationMode(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT)
->getResult();
```

#### User.php

```
class User {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Property", mappedBy="users", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")
     */
     protected $properties;
}
```

#### Property.php

```
class Property {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="properties", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_property",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="property_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
     protected $users;
}
```

Comment: does apc have enough free memory to cache your objects?

Comment: @meze: Yes, enabled 1GB, which is more than enough for this case. APC version is 3.1.7, if matters.

Comment: Could you check if this works in 2.2? It has been released today and some fixes to caching mechanisms have been applied.

Comment: @Ocramius: Thanks a lot for your answer! According to changelog for doctrine 2.2 my issue is fixed there, but I should wait when Symfony is released with Doctrine 2.2 support to modify configs properly.

Comment: Just swapping submodule references to give it a try could work (obviously not for production... You should reset changes after trying). The DoctrineBundle will will surely need some refactoring...

Comment: Changing just deps files doesn't help, because of changes in AnnotationReader, which throws some errors, but I don't have time this week to work on this project, so will just put this on hold for this week.

Comment: What is the configuration of your result cache driver (at EntityManager Configuration level) ?

Comment: @Florian: I think it is quiet obvious - `result_cache_driver: apc`, or I did understand your question wrong.

Comment: @AntonBabenko no it's obviously the answer I was waiting for :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the Doctrine JIRA issue related to a caching issue which is the closest to the problem's description:

<strike>http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-217</strike>
https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/2861

My opinion is that point is fixed in Doctrine 2.2

Comment: As @Ocramius said in comments it has been fixed in Doctrine 2.2, but I am waiting for updated DoctrineBundle, so I can verify it in my symfony2 project. Thanks for your answer and time!

Comment: Someone started a bounty asking for a reference to an official source... Still waiting for my reps

Comment: My bounty has expired before you asnwered to the question. I remember it was somebody else, who offered same bounty after me. I accept your answer now.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem as in a question, except for I'm using Memcache instead of APC. Using Symfony 2.3 and Doctrine 2.2

Comment: Link is broken.  Is there any work around?  I can't seem to accomplish this in 2.3.3 as Doctrine seems to not use its own find% methods which prevents me simply overriding a repo method to force caching.