# Doctrine result cache bug with LEFT JOIN ... WITH condition

Tags: doctrine, symfony, left-join, dql

I tend to find answers before I need to post a question here, but today I can't seem to find out what is wrong.

We're using Doctrine 2.1.2 in a Symfony 2 app, and in a repository we have two methods that use almost the same query.
The only difference between method A and method B is that there is a condition added to a JOIN that is common to both queries.

The problem is that Doctrine seems to use the same result cache for both queries.
When we call method A, method B uses the cache from A, and the other way around.

I have been using expireResultCache(true) and useResultCache(false), to no avail.

Here's what the queries look like:

```
-- method A

SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c FROM MyBundle:ObjectA a INDEX BY a.id
LEFT JOIN a.fkObjectB b
LEFT JOIN a.fkObjectC c

-- method B
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c FROM MyBundle:ObjectA a INDEX BY a.id
LEFT JOIN a.fkObjectB b WITH b.some_field IS NULL
LEFT JOIN a.fkObjectC c
```

When I use getSQL(), I see that they result in different queries as expected. The generated queries, when run independantly in database, do generate different results.

This leads me to believe that it may be an annoying result cache bug, where Doctrine does not cache the conditions for JOINs, but only the table names.

Is this a bug, or is there something I can do?

**EDIT** Still happening in Doctrine 2.1.6.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you have is fixed in Doctrine 2.2. I have similar problem related to result cache and here is [my question&answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629640/symfony2-doctrine2-is-not-caching-results-of-joined-entities).

Comment: Just in case someone stumbles on this old question: the problem lied between chair and keyboard.

We were not taking into account the fact that managed entities' array collections properties would stay the same and not be updated by successive queries.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on [michel v's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331308/doctrine-result-cache-bug-with-left-join-with-condition#comment14202428_9334183), Doctrine 2 is fetching the same object instance both times via the [identity map pattern](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#entities-and-the-identity-map).

Calling:

```
EntityManager#clear()
```

clears the identity map and forces the EntityManager to fetch a fresh copy of the object from the database.