# Symfony 2.3 and Doctrine 2.2 + Memcache not caching Many To Many joined relations

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, relation

I found a question explaining the problem as I have - [Symfony2 + Doctrine2 is not caching results of joined entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629640/symfony2-doctrine2-is-not-caching-results-of-joined-entities), but the answer doesn't help, because I'm using Sf 2.3 and Doctrine 2.3.6. Also, instead of APC I use MemCache for query and result caching.

config.yml

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
        query_cache_driver:
            type: memcache
            host: "%result_memcache_host%"
            port: "%result_memcache_port%"
            instance_class: Memcache
        result_cache_driver:
            type: memcache
            host: "%result_memcache_host%"
            port: "%result_memcache_port%"
            instance_class: Memcache
```

In controller:

```
$rs = $this->getEM()
        ->getRepository('MainBundle:Channels')
        ->findByIdFullData($id)
        ->useResultCache(true, 900, 'channel' . $id)
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

In repository:

```
public function findByIdFullData($id)
{
    $rs = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c', 'al')
        ->leftJoin('c.audioLanguage', 'al')
        ->where('c.id = :id')
        ->andWhere('c.active = 1')
        ->setParameter('id', $id);

    return $rs->getQuery();
}
```

`audioLanguage` is a ManyToMany relation between channels and languages and every time i get a query to DB while trying to access it in twig or by calling `getAudioLanguage()`

What could be wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the same cache key for every query, remove third parameter from useResultCache. And maybe you should specify Hydration mode in `getOneOrNullResult` to `Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_OBJECT`? Good luck.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I use unique names for cache name, just cleared some unnecessary code in a question (edited now) :) Setting hydration mode as You suggest also doesn't change anything. By the way, I'm using Translatable from Doctrine extensions, and I set Object hydration there.

Comment: Have a look on my other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169763/symfony-2-3-gedmo-doctrine-extensions-translatable-caching/27173280#27173280

Comment: I don't think that's related. Even without translatable many-to-many relations aren't cached.

Comment: Similar resolved problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336953/doctrine-result-cache-not-caching-a-query-with-a-join

Comment: Upgraded Doctrine to 2.3.6, but still the same. Couldn't figure out how to make use of the link You provided. Are You suggesting I should _create my own "result cache"_?

Comment: I don't know if its related, but maybe. Have look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In our project main project (doctrine 2.4) we have a custom cache tagging feature, and every cached query is handled by this method (it re-sets resultCacheDriver for every query):

```
public function add($query, $lifetime = null)
    {
        $ownRedis = new RedisCache();
        /** @var $query Query */
        $query->useResultCache(true,$lifetime);
        $redis = $query->getQueryCacheProfile()->getResultCacheDriver();
        $ownRedis->setRedis($redis->getRedis());
        $query->setResultCacheDriver($ownRedis);
        self::$_queries[] = $query;
    }
```